# What is the main difference between Numba Pro and Theano/pyautodiff for GPU calculations?

Tags: python, gpu, theano, numba, numba-pro

Both Numba Pro and pyautodiff based on Theano supports conversion of Python code into GPU machine code. Theano will also allow symbolic derivation of the resulted syntax tree, but this is outside the scope of my question.

My question is whether there are technical limitations in one or the other framework, which would make the code less efficient.

Comment: Apparently someone looked at this already: https://gist.github.com/nouiz/5492778

Comment: And this: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/theano-users/Y-LN5Qsp0P8